# Flutter Mockito - Mock Throwing Exceptions

Tags: unit-testing, exception, flutter, mockito

Just started using Mockito in Flutter:

I want to mock an exception being thrown when a method is called. So I did this:

```
when(mockInstance.foo(input).thenThrow(ArgumentError);
```

But then when expecting that it will throw an ArgumentError:

```
expect(mockInstance.foo(input), throwsArgumentError);
```

I run flutter test and the output is that the test failed even though it states that it is indeed an ArgumentError:

```
 ArgumentError 
 package:mockito/src/mock.dart 346:7                             
 PostExpectation.thenThrow.<fn>
 package:mockito/src/mock.dart 123:37                            
 Mock.noSuchMethod
 package:-/--/---/Instance.dart 43:9  MockInstance.foo
 tests/Instance_test.dart 113:26 ensureArgumentErrorIsThrown
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

If you need to mock an exception, both of these approaches should work:

1. Mock the call and provide the `expect` function with a function that is expected to throw once it's executed (Mockito seems to fail automatically if any test throws an exception outside the `expect` function):

   ```
   when(mockInstance.foo(input))
     .thenThrow(ArgumentError);

   expect(
     () => mockInstance.foo(input), // or just mockInstance.foo(input)
     throwsArgumentError,
   );
   ```
2. In case it's an async call, and you are catching the exception on a try-catch block and returning something, you can use `then.Answer` :

   ```
   when(mockInstance.foo(input))
     .thenAnswer((_) => throw ArgumentError());

   final a = await mockInstance.foo(input);

   // assert
   verify(...);
   expect(...)
   ```
3. If the exception is not thrown by a mock:

   ```
   expect(
     methodThatThrows(),
     throwsA(isA<YourCustomException>()),
   );
   ```

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem. Try

```
expect(() => mockInstance.foo(input), throwsArgumentError);
```

Here is an example class with all tests passing

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

void main() {
  test("",(){
    var mock = new MockA();
    when(mock.foo1()).thenThrow(new ArgumentError());

    expect(() => mock.foo1(), throwsArgumentError);
  });

  test("",(){
    var mock = new MockA();
    when(mock.foo2()).thenThrow(new ArgumentError());

    expect(() => mock.foo2(), throwsArgumentError);
  });

  test("",(){
    var mock = new MockA();
    when(mock.foo3()).thenThrow(new ArgumentError());

    expect(() => mock.foo3(), throwsArgumentError);
  });

  test("",(){
    var mock = new MockA();
    when(mock.foo4()).thenThrow(new ArgumentError());

    expect(() => mock.foo4(), throwsArgumentError);
  });
}

class MockA extends Mock implements A {}

class A {
  void foo1() {}
  int foo2() => 3;
  Future foo3() async {}
  Future<int> foo4() async => Future.value(3);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation as to why we need to pass the arrow function inside `expect(() => actual, matcher)`?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't give you any valid explanation.